# How to calculate the new $x$, and $y$ coordinates of a scaled rotated rectangle?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, rotations, programming, rectangles

I want to scale a rotated rectangle around it's centre point and find the new $x$ and $y$ coordinates - In this diagram given I know $(x, y), \theta , w , h , nw$, and $nh$ - does anyone ideas how I calculate $(nx, ny)$?

I'm not massively familiar with vector math or vector notation so please bear with me.

[image: Updated diagram including axis for clarification]

EDIT: Sorry, I've updated the diagram to show the rotation origin is not (0,0) - it is unknown.

Comment: Note this is a _negative_ rotation (clockwise).

Comment: Is the given angle of rotation $\large{\pmb{\theta}}$ measured from $x$-axis?

Comment: @YNK yes it is from the x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes the center has coordinates `(0,0)`. The *op* does not specify where the origin is actually, and which way *x* and *y* point to.

Split the path to the corner into two vectors (blue and red) and take their horizontal and vertical projections

[image: fig1]

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  x &= x_1 - x_2 \\
  y & = y_1 + y_2 \\
\end{aligned} $$

I have marked the congruent angles (same measure) in order to find that

$$ \begin{aligned}
 x_1 & = \left( \tfrac{h}{2} \right) \sin \theta \\
 y_1 & = \left( \tfrac{h}{2} \right) \cos \theta \\
 x_2 & = \left( \tfrac{w}{2} \right) \cos \theta \\
 y_2 & = \left( \tfrac{w}{2} \right) \sin \theta
\end{aligned}$$

Now you can put it all together.

Comment: This is actually just another way of putting it together. This also assumes that the x- and y-axis run through the point of rotation. You get $x_{new}=(\frac h2\sin\theta-\frac w2\cos\theta)*nw/w$ and $y_{new}=(\frac h2\cos\theta+\frac w2\sin\theta)*nw/w$. Which is just the same as $x_{new}=(x\sin\theta-y\cos\theta)*n$ and $y_{new}=(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)*n$.

Comment: @JaMoin - yes you are correct. The _op_ does not specify where the origin is.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou sorry I didn't specify the origin as I don't know those coordinates, it is the center of the rectangle though.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the x- and y-axis run through the point of rotation. The rotation matrix for an angle $\theta$ is as follows:

$$\begin{bmatrix}{\cos{\theta}} & {\sin{\theta}}\\{-\sin{\theta}} & {\cos{\theta}}\end{bmatrix}$$

To rotate your x coordinates you multiply them by this matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}{\cos{\theta}} & {\sin{\theta}}\\{-\sin{\theta}} & {\cos{\theta}}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}{x\cos{\theta}+y\sin{\theta}}\\{y\cos{\theta}-x\sin{\theta}}\end{bmatrix}$$

Then you just multiply them by your scaling factor n which is just $n=nw/w$:

$$x_{new}=(x\cos{\theta}+y\sin{\theta})n$$
$$y_{new}=(y\cos{\theta}-x\sin{\theta})n$$

The factor n is the same for all lengths because all lengths scale the same which is why you can just multiply by the factor you get from the ratio of nw to w (you could also use $n=nh/h$, it doesn't make a difference).

Answer (score 1):

Define $\alpha = \dfrac{nw}{w} $, and $\beta = \dfrac{nh}{h} $

Attach a reference frame to the rectangle, and let its origin be the center of both rectangles $(x_0, y_0)$, then for the unscaled rectangle, the relation between coordinates with respect to the unscaled rectangle and the $xy$ plane is given by

$ r = r_0 + R(\theta) r' $

where $r = (x, y) $,$r_0 = (x_0, y_0) $ and $r' = (x', y') $ the coordinates with respect to the unscaled rectangle (in its own reference frame), and

$R(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta && - \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta && \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} $

Now, apply the scale, by replacing $r'$ with $ S r' $ where

$ S= \begin{bmatrix} \alpha && 0 \\ 0 && \beta \end{bmatrix} $

Putting it all together

$r_2 = r_0 + R S ( R^T (r_1 - r_0) ) = R S R^T r_1 + (I_2 - R S R^T) r_0$

where $r_1 = (x_1, y_1) $ is the original (unscaled) point in the $xy$ plane and $r_2$ is the scaled point.

If this seems too complicated, you can simply first unrotate the rectangle by appling a negative rotation, i.e. a rotation by $(-\theta)$, then scale using $\alpha $ and $\beta$, and finally rotate again by $\theta$.  And this is essentially what the equation above is stating.  Let's do these three steps:

First negative rotation, this is a rotation by $(-\theta)$, so the corresponding rotation matrix is the inverse of $R(\theta)$ which is equal to the transpose of $R(\theta) $, hence the image of $r_1$ is

$ r_1' = r_0 + R^T (r_1 - r_0) $

Secondly, we'll apply scaling using the matrix $S$ where the center of scaling is $r_0$ (i.e. $r_0$ is the invariant point), then the image of $r_1' $ is

$r_1'' = r_0 + S (r_1' - r_0 ) = r_0 + S R^T (r_1 - r_0) $

Finally, we'll rotate $r_1"$ about $r_0$ by $\theta$ to bring it back.  The final image is

$r_2 = r_0 + R (r_1'' - r_0) = r_0 + R S R^T (r_1 - r_0) $

And this proves the equation stated above.

Answer (score 0):

[image: ScaledRotatedRectangle]

We start by drawing the line segments $AP$, $A_nP$, $AQ$, and $A_nQ$, which are parallel to $AD$, $CD$, $x$-axis, and $y$-axis respectively.

Now, we determine the lengths of the two line segments $AP$ and $A_nP$ as shown below.

$$ AP = \dfrac{\left(n-1\right)}{2}h\space$$
$$A_nP = \dfrac{\left(n-1\right)}{2}w$$

We, then, apply Pythagoras theorem to the right angled triangle $APA_n$ to obtain,
$$AA_n = \dfrac{\left(n-1\right)}{2}\sqrt{h^2+w^2}.$$

Finally, we use the right angled triangle $A_nQA$ to find the lengths of the two line segments $A_nQ$ and $AQ$.

$$AQ = AA_n\cos\left(\theta\right)=\dfrac{\left(n-1\right)}{2}\sqrt{h^2+w^2}\cos\left(\theta\right)$$

$$A_nQ = AA_n\sin\left(\theta\right)=\dfrac{\left(n-1\right)}{2}\sqrt{h^2+w^2}\sin\left(\theta\right)$$

Therefore, we have,
$$x_n = x - AQ = x - \dfrac{\left(n-1\right)}{2}\sqrt{h^2+w^2}\cos\left(\theta\right) \qquad\text{and}$$

$$y_n = y + A_nQ =  y+ \dfrac{\left(n-1\right)}{2}\sqrt{h^2+w^2}\sin\left(\theta\right).\qquad\quad\space$$

Comment: What is `n` in this formula? the Scale factor?

Comment: @GlennFlannagan Yes, that is the scale factor.